# User input for date filter

Tags: excel, vba, msgbox

I have some VBA code that applies a date filter to a dataset for further work. Currently the date filter is applied based on predefined conditions:

```
Worksheets("PSE Data").Activate

    StartDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), Day(Date))
    EndDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 3, Day(Date))


    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PSE_Data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=17, _
                                            Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, _
                                            Operator:=xlAnd, _
                                            Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PSE_Data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=6, _
                                            Criteria1:="M"

    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PSE_Data").Sort
    .SortFields.Add Key:= _
    Range("PSE_Data" & "[Sugg Start Date]"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
    Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .Apply
    End With
```

What I want to do is replace the StartDate and EndDate with user input values from a pop up box. Could you help?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim StartDate, EndDate As Date

StartDate = InputBox("Enter start date: ")
EndDate = InputBox("Enter end date: ")
```

Comment: This answer the question, but you should explain why. Also. notice that coding `Dim StartDate, EndDate As Date`, only `EndDate` is being defined as `Date`. `StartDate` is being declared as `Variant`. It should be `Dim StartDate as Date, EndDate As Date`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a typical way:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date

    With Application
        StartDate = CDate(.InputBox(Prompt:="enter startdate mm/dd/yyyy", Type:=2))
        EndDate = CDate(.InputBox(Prompt:="enter enddate mm/dd/yyyy", Type:=2))
        MsgBox StartDate & vbCrLf & EndDate
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I've got a couple of additional questions:

- I'd like the date format to me dd/mm/yyyy. I'm assuming to change to this format I need to change the "Type" number. Is that right, if so what type do I need to set.

- If the user enters a date in the wrong format, how will this behave, can I get it to prompt for them to retry?

Comment: @dnaylor93 a Type of 2 bring it in as a `String` *cDate()* in my system assumes m/d/yyyy.  I don't know about your system.....................experiment and let us know..............

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that uses a function to get and validate user input.  It uses `Application.InputBox` to prompt the user for input, and then uses `IsDate` to check for a valid date.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

'prompt user for start date
Dim StartDate As Variant
StartDate = GetUserInputDate("start")
If StartDate = False Then Exit Sub 'user cancelled
StartDate = CDate(StartDate)

'prompt user for end date
Dim EndDate As Variant
EndDate = GetUserInputDate("end")
If EndDate = False Then Exit Sub 'user cancelled
EndDate = CDate(EndDate)

ActiveSheet.ListObjects("PSE_Data").Range.AutoFilter Field:=17, _
                                            Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, _
                                            Operator:=xlAnd, _
                                            Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate


End Sub


Function GetUserInputDate(ByVal promptPart As String) As Variant

    Dim temp As Variant

    Do
        temp = Application.InputBox("Enter " & promptPart & " date (ie. mm/dd/yyyy):", "Date?")
    Loop Until (temp = False) Or (IsDate(temp))

    GetUserInputDate = temp

End Function
```